# Problems with the home directory

Tags: 20.04, directory, gui, home-directory, interface

All the files that are in the home directory are showing up on my Ubuntu iterface. I created a directory called problems (last directory in the image) to put the directories that are in the home directory, that way they won't be shown on my interface. This is a image from my interface:
[files out of home directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc2EM.jpg)

About the image: The home directory is the first directory and the problems directory is the last.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Please add output of `ls -la "$HOME/Desktop"` and `cat "$HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs"`

Answer (score 1):

The files displayed on your desktop are controlled by the value of the

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR
```

variable, which is usually set int the config file

```
~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

On my system is set as follows:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
```

I suggest you edit the file indicated, and set the value to be the place where you want the environment to show all the folders, shortcuts and files on your desktop.

Comment: @Community False. Looks good to me.

Comment: Community Bot needs a power cycle.